# Why does IMemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync return "TItem?" (nullable) instead of "TItem"?

Tags: c#, .net, nullable-reference-types, memorycache

The extension method [`GetOrCreateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync) for `IMemoryCache`:

```cs
public static async Task<TItem?> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(this IMemoryCache cache, object key, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<TItem>> factory)
{
    if (!cache.TryGetValue(key, out object? result))
    {
        using ICacheEntry entry = cache.CreateEntry(key);

        result = await factory(entry).ConfigureAwait(false);
        entry.Value = result;
    }

    return (TItem?)result;
}
```

Why do they returns `TItem?` instead of just `TItem`? Assuming my `factory` method never returns null, is it safe to assume it would never be `null` and just ignore it with null-forgiving operator `!`?

```cs
public async Task<Foo> GetFooAsync()
    => (await cache.GetOrCreateAsync("Foo", async _ => new Foo()))!
```

Comment: the reason it returns a nullable is because of the `?` after the type. This symbolises a nullable variable. The reason it probably returns like a nullable is because `result` could be null, its not safe to assume that it won't be null. I suggest implementing a null check before using the return data.

Comment: @rbdeenk I believe they can just as well cast it to `TItem` instead of `TItem?`. But you are right that I want to know why they don't do that, there may be a situation that somehow it could be `null`. However that's extra logic for getting `Foo` incase it's null (basically almost copy the factory method)

Comment: `GetOrCreate()` is only a part of the whole interface. Maybe other methods allow writing cache values that are `null`?

Comment: have a look at this post on the dotnet github https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77266

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride yep you are right, per the Github comment. So if I do not write the cache myself with other method (or no `null` value) I can safely ignore it I guess.

Comment: @rbdeenk Thanks, that's the correct one. Somehow I missed that one when Googling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This [github post](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77266) has some important factors as to why they chose to make it a nullable return type.
Here are a couple things to consider.

It is possible to cache a null value according to [eerhardt](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77266#issuecomment-1286050159).

In the post Stephen Toub states [the following](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77266#issuecomment-1288329367):

> One of our overarching principles for nullable annotations in the core libraries it that they should never lie and say null isn't a possible result when in fact it is. This does lead to some cases where a method is annotated as returning a T? even if null is rare or relegated to a corner-case, e.g. Activator.CreateInstance returns T? because for example it can actually be null if you specify a Nullable as the type, but it means the nullability of the return value can be trusted: if it says it's non-nullable, then it won't ever be null, and callers don't need to guard against dereferencing null. The principles are outlined in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/coding-guidelines/api-guidelines/nullability.md.

I hope this gives a clear idea why they chose to make it nullable.
In your case if you are 100% sure that you won't cache any nullables you could in theory ignore the fact that it can return a null value. Although I don't recommend it in any case you program grows/ changes and requires this to be possible.